# htaccess RewriteRule with parameters to specific location

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hyperlink, parameters

I have a page which has a link as:

```
http://www.example.com/listings.php?packageType=luxury-travel
```

Which I'd like to send to:

```
http://www.example.com/luxury-travel
```

And also:

```
http://www.example.com/listings.php?packageType=luxury-travel&packageTypeSub=remote-luxury-retreats
```

To go to:

```
http://www.example.com/luxury-travel/remote-luxury-retreats
```

I have used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /listings.php?packageType=$1&packageTypeSub=$2 [L]
```

Which ends up affecting other pages which I have such as:

```
http://www.example.com/about-us
```

I have also tried placing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Before. Also tried playing with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^packageType=([^&]+) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &packageType=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /listings.php?packageType=$1 [L]
```

Which just give me a 404 error on both links. Anyone have any ideas? Would have thought this would have been a simple one!

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.*]+)/([^\.*]+)/?$ listings.php?packageType=$1&packageTypeSub=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.*]+)/?$ listings.php?packageType=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. tried this, but didn't seem to work. Caused an error on other pages like /contact, etc. Also didn't work fully for links like: 
http://www.example.com/luxury-travel/remote-luxury-retreats

Comment: Amend: Managed to get it to work OK, but having issues with other links? Have edited original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+listings\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)packageType=([^&]+)&packageTypeSub=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /listings.php?packageType=$1&packageTypeSub=$2 [L]
```

Note that if only `packageType` is available, the rules would redirect to `http://www.example.com/luxury-travel/` (note the `/` at the end) to help differentiate it from links like `http://www.example.com/about-us`.

If that's not an option, then you would have add rules that specifically provide page/link names.

Comment: Thanks Ravi. I ended up getting re-direct loops with this one.

Comment: Thanks Ravi. I've tested it and it does also work.
I do though have an issue. I should have mentioned I have other pages too which need directing:
http://example.com/location.php?place=vancouver
to
http://example.com/vancouver

Also I need to work on:
http://example.com/product.php?packageType=luxury-travel&id=42
to
http://example.com/luxury-travel/private-touring/product-name/42

Comment: Also, I like how this automatically redirects, but for some reason even though I have absolute paths for images, some come up missing.
Also the automatic redirect only works for the second level.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited and removed some of the development code as it wasn't working.

After a lot of headscratching I finally found a solution which works:

```
# Rewrite specific pages - listings
# Allow packageType
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+listings\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)packageType=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&packageTypeSub=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,NC,L]

# Allow packageTypeSub
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+listings\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)packageType=([^&]+)&packageTypeSub=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,NC,L]

# Ignore the images folder allowing images to display
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(upload-images) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /listings.php?packageType=$1&packageTypeSub=$2 [L]
```

The main issue was the upload-images folder which contains all the images for the site packages was being blocked. I managed to exclude this folder from the rewrite rules and it now seems to be working. Thanks all for your help. Hope this helps someone else in future.

Comment: Great that you found a solution! It's better, however, to keep the original question, and post your solution as an answer. That way, people with a similar problem can find their problem (your question) and see a solution.

Comment: Cheers Lee, I kept in the original question, just stripped out some of the update edits i added which were, useless ;)

Comment: I see. But the part from the word * Solution *  till the end of the post doesn't belong in the question. It's an answer, and a good one, apparently (it worked for you :)). SO encourages answering your own question, and you can even choose it as the accepted answer.